# recurring payment backend system for municipality (utilities)

Tags: api, payment-processing

I'm able and willing to develop a frontend web-based UI (and any server-side code to support the frontend) but I'm stuggling to find a proven, low-cost automatic payment processing system with a nice API that I can use to handle the actual payments.

I envision the system will only accept checking account payments (no credit cards).  Once the user supplies the relevant info, they will be automatically billed for their village utility use every month, based on that month's usage of course.  I'll use the UI to allow the user to track history, change billing info, etc.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution that worked for you? I've been on the hunt for something similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Authorize.Net offers eCheck services](http://www.authorize.net/solutions/merchantsolutions/merchantservices/echeck/). Their APIs are all easy to use so this one should meet your criteria.